# Find $P(X > 1)$ if $X$ is standard normal

Tags: probability

$f(x) = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2} dx$

find $P(X > 1)$

This is $X$ ~ $Norm(0, 1)$.

$P(X > 1)  = 1 - P(X \leq 1) = 1 - 2 \phi(1) = 1-2(1-\phi(-1)) = 1 - 2(1-0.1587) = -0.6826$.

Yikes. Negative number. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First your $f(x)$ has an error in that there should be no $2$ in the numerator of $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, further, expression for $f$ is independent of $x$ and unnecessary. It's not clear why you are manipulating the expression for $P(X>1)$ here since you're going to need to resort to numerically integrating the Gaussian at some point anyway. In my opinion, the easiest way to do this problem is to depend on the Empirical rule to conclude that $P(0\leq X \leq 1) \approx 0.6827/2$ and so $P(X>1) \approx 0.5- 0.6827/2 = 0.15865$.

Comment: Please concoct better titles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let´s say the pdf is  $$f(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$$

(without the integral)

Now you want to calculate $P(X> 1)$ which is

$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2} dx$

First we can factor out $2$.

$2\cdot \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2} dx=2\cdot P(Y>1)$, where $Y$ is standard normal distributed as $Y\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$

Since $Y$ is symmetric distributed around $0$ we can say that $2\cdot P(Y> 1)= P(|Y|>1)$.

From the [68–95–99.7](http://68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7%20rule) rule you probably know that $1-P(|Y|>1)=P(|Y|<1)=0.6827$

Consequently $P(|Y|>1)=1-0.6827=0.3173=P(X>1)$

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by $\phi(t)$ you mean the area in the left tail of a normal distribution. If so, then the two below is incorrect and should be removed:
$$P(X > 1) = 1 - P(X \leq 1) = 1 - \color{red}{2}\phi(1) = \dots$$

Answer (score -1):

[image]
thus $$P(X\le1)=\phi(1)$$

$$your answer =1-\phi(1)$$